# Expectation of the "second eigenvalue" of a random binary matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

For a real matrix $A$, define its *second eigenvalue* to be $\max_{i\ge 2}|\lambda_i|$, where $\lambda_1\ge\lambda_2\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

What is the expectation of the second eigenvalue of a random $\{0,1\}$, $n×n$ matrix, where each entry of the matrix is a Bernoulli random variable with probability $p\in(0,1)$, independent of all other entries?

I am interested in known results for large $n$'s. Any reference might be helpful.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but if you require your matrix to be symmetric with zeros along the diagonal, then you are (almost) asking for the expected spectral gap of a random graph ... almost because the first eigenvalue should be one most of the time, since in the limit the random graph will be connected almost surely, though I don't know enough about random graph theory to quantify this. Maybe searching the literature about that problem will be helpful? For example, googling turns up this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0425 and many other papers.